# How can I disable landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I tried some code and project settings but application still changing orientation. How can I make only portrait orientation?

XCode Version: 7.3.1, App Deployment Target: 6.0

**In Settings Device Orientation only Portrait selected.**

[image]

Info.plist file :

[image]

Code in .m file :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Note: I do not have any Objective-C experience.

Comment: please add contents of the project's Info.plist.  Specifically, the section called "Supported Interface Orientations", which is set by those checkboxes

Comment: There is no Info.plist file in my project. I have searched and i couldn't find.

Comment: Search in build settings, under packaging section.

Comment: No wayyy. Who started this project lol just recreate project I'd say. Sounds messy..

Comment: I didn't start this project but i have to do it now. I have founded plist file in the folder. I have added image of file check out question.

Comment: iOS 6.0 is iOS version you test on or you just set it randomly and test on other version?

Answer (score 0):

Select the project (top item in the navigator).  The second section is called "Deployment Info".  Within it are a group of checkboxes for device orientation.

[image]

Comment: I have already did it. There is only Portrait selected but did not work. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all rotating delegate methods and remove all other `Supported interface orientations`, there should only be **one** and it should be on:

**Portrait (bottom home button)**

So delete the 2nd/bottom `Supported interface orientations (i...`

Comment: What if you remove all rotating delegate methods, tick all Device Orientation checkboxes then untick them all, then only tick portrait?

Comment: That's weird.. usually one start a project then untick those immediately without any methods then khallas, it should work.. :/

Comment: Okay well after you uploaded your Info.plist, this is my updated answer. :)

Comment: Still does not change anything :(

Comment: No no no no.. Shift + Cmd + K... then delete the app from iPhone/Simulator, then build again.. What the hell man :/

Comment: No mate, create new project and copy things over except any settings file like bundle stuff, Info etc. Run and see what you get then change 1 thing at a time from old project to see if it affects your rotation. I dont know what else to do sorry habibi :D

Comment: There has to be some code for stop that. 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' is it correct method?

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Pleasure bud, sorry tho! :(